# change background color of li element based on selected page

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, menu, navigation

I want to know how can i change the background color of a anchor element when it's children is selected.

for example if i have a navigation where

```
<ul>
    <li><a>home</a></li>
    <li class="has-dropdown"> 
        <a href="somewhere.html"> parent </a>
        <ul>
            <li class="clickedthis has-dropdown"><a href="something.html">list 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="clickedthis"><a href="something.html">list 1</a></li>
                    <li>list 4</li>
                    <li>list 5</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>list 2</li>
            <li>list 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and i clicked the the first link, i want it to change the background color of the parent when it loads on the next page.

so what ever current page it's on, the parent of that anchor element gets the background color set.

---

for example [the dnn site](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/)

if i go to one of the subpages from the nav the parent element turn blue

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea would be to apply a class to the element that you want to change, like `.selected`, which sets the background color.

Since your `href` values seem to be directed to static .html files, it would be a matter of setting that class on the appropriate `<li>` in each file.

But there are better ways of managing state if you use a backend technology that conditionally applies the class, preferably to a shared header snippet of markup, depending on the page or route being served.

Comment: i want it to only apply the class that has the background color when the sub items were selected and i got redirected to that subpage. so on the load of the new page the background color would be the  `.active`. and the href isnt static. ( i dont know if im wording this right)

Comment: There's no way to answer this without knowing more about your backend architecture and how these pages are being generated.

Comment: It helps, you've formulated your question poorly, and should've tagged this as a .NET issue. It also sounds like you might need to read the documentation a bit more. There are also other related questions on StackOverflow. Have you tried searching before posting your question?